# Element is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.filter.FormScope

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have a form field and when filling the form , i am getting the error

```
"Element  is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.filter.FormScope".
```

It was pointing to the following code:-

```
if(arguments.action eq 'addProficency')
            {
//
//

            CertificationArray = ArrayNew(1);

                //add the Certificationes
                for(i = 0; i lte Event["Certificationes"]; i = i + 1)
                {
                    CertificationView = CreateObject("Component","com.idl.app.cmn.cfobj.Certification.CertificationView");

                    CertificationView.SetLine1(Event["Certificationline1_" & i]);

    CertificationView.SetLine2(Event["Certificationline2_" & i]);
                    CertificationView.SetCity(Event["Certificationcity_" & i]);
                    CertificationView.SetState(Event["Certificationstate_" & i]);
                    CertificationView.SetZip(Event["Certificationzip_" & i]);

                    isRequired = false;

                    if(form.Required eq i)
                    {
                        isRequired = true;
                    }

                    ArrayAppend(CertificationArray,CertificationView);
                }
}
```

When I comment out "

```
CreateObject("Component","com.idl.app.cmn.cfobj.Certification.CertificationView");

                        CertificationView.SetLine1(Event["Certificationline1_" & i]);

        CertificationView.SetLine2(Event["Certificationline2_" & i]);
```

"
I am not getting the error.What does the Error mean?How to correct it?
Thanks 
Vas

Comment: @Vas - Should the index really start at 0? How do you indicate zero Event["Certificationes"]?

Comment: @Vas - What ended up being the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with dhorn. Do a cfdump to see what fields are defined.   **Update:**  I noticed your `for` loop starts at zero (0), not one (1). Typically, dynamic form field counters start at one (1). So is 0 *really* the correct starting value in your case?  If so, how are you representing zero event certifications?

> What does the Error mean

It just means you are referencing a form field that does not exist, or the field name you are using is invalid. When you use array notation, the error message is a little different than if you were using the standard dot notation.

```
<!--- result 1 --->
<cfset foo = form.FakeFieldNameThatDoesNotReallyExist />
Element FAKEFIELDNAMETHATDOESNOTREALLYEXIST is undefined in FORM. 

<!--- result 2 --->
<cfset foo = form["FakeFieldNameThatDoesNotReallyExist"] />
Element FakeFieldNameThatDoesNotReallyExist is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.filter.FormScope.
```

Comment: it says "vote too old to be changed,unless answer is edited."Please make some cosmetic editions ,it can be voted up again.

Answer (score 4):

It's good practice to ensure an element exists before working with it.

```
if (structKeyExists(Event, "Certificationline1_" & i)) {
  CertificationView.SetLine1(Event["Certificationline1_" & i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that Event["Certificationline1_" & i] and Event["Certificationline2_" & i] are actually defined. Try a cfdump and see if they show up there.

Edit: missed the word cfdump.